# No attachment when using crontab to send mail

Tags: linux, email, cron, attachment

I use a really simple script to send an attachment every day in my email. When I run the script manually, it works fine, but when I run it using crontab, I receive the email, but without the attachment.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
uuencode ~/Documents/memo.txt memo.txt | mail email@email.com
```

I'm using ElementaryOS (ubuntu based).

Ideas?

Comment: A common problem for scripts that work fine in interactive mode and not in crontab is the environment. You should add a line to print the environment in your script, print it in an interactive session and look at the differences. That should explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add full path of the uuencode in the crontab. First check that what is the full path by using the following command.

```
which uuencode
```

Then add it to the crontab.